# Get thumbnail image from video not working with PHP and ffmpeg (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I have generated a $cmd string:

> ffmpeg -i /home/alen/www/mysite/video/Guitarist-139.mp4 -an -ss 0 -s
>   1280x720 /home/alen/www/mysite/img/Guitarist-139.jpg

then I have typing a command in PHP:

```
shell_exec($cmd);
```

but not working,

then I have pasted this string in terminal but in terminal work perfectly.

What is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of the command? shell_exec returns you the result - which will point you to the error reason

Try escaping the command before executing with escapeshellcmd or individual arguments with escapeshellarg before passing to ffmpeg via shell. File path you passed has slashes, which needs backslashed/ escaped atleast

Comment: I have tried with backslashes and escapeshellcmd, not working. I also have tried exec(), and for ffmpeg I have tried full path "usr/bin/ffmpeg", this returns nothing.  But when I try "ls -l" then display the list where is the "index.php".

Comment: What is the return output of your shell_exec says?  There can be permission issue, ffmpeg path issue and some other like these. Does your pho runs as same user of your terminal runs? Tried with ffmpeg full path ... You need to look for output / error logs to find the reason quickly

Comment: the output is blank, I tried everything but still nothing work. How can I see witch user runs php?

Comment: That means it's not going to command execution, run only command 'ffmpeg' & see if it says anything about ffmpeg. Change your CMd to 'whoami' this will return the user that running the PHP. Another thing just came in mind - how are you trying to see the output? Should be - $out = shell_exec($cmd); var_dump($out); - you may know thins already and doing so ... But just in case.

Comment: In this case return null. I tried PHP-FFMpeg and I pasted "basic usage" and return fatal error:          Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutionFailureException' with message 'ffmpeg failed to execute command '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-ss' '00:00:01.00' '-i' 'video/Guitarist-139.mp4' '-vframes' '1' '-f' 'image2' 'frame.jpg'' in ...